# CSVLayer: Unsupported query parameters

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I have a CSVLayer with a number of features to display on top of my basemap. The layer is added to the basemap as follows:

```
    var map = new Map("map", {...});
    var basemap = new ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer(...);
    map.addLayer(basemap);
    map.reorderLayer(basemap, 0);

    var layer = new CSVLayer(
        "data.csv",
        {
            latitudeFieldName: "y",
            longitudeFieldName: "x",
        }
    );

    var popup = new InfoWindowLite(
        null,
        domConstruct.create("div")
    );
    popup.resize(200, 100);
    popup.startup();
    map.setInfoWindow(popup);

    var template = new InfoTemplate();
    template.setTitle("${title}");
    template.setContent("Foo Bar");
    layer.setInfoTemplate(template);

    var marker = new SimpleMarkerSymbol("solid", 15, null, new Color([255, 0, 0, 1]));
    var renderer = new SimpleRenderer(marker);
    layer.setRenderer(renderer);

    map.addLayer(layer);
```

This works fine as long as there are 18 or less rows (= features) in the CSV. As soon as I have 19 or more entries, the above fails. Inspecting the CSVLayer object it appears that it loads fine but when it's supposed to be rendered, it fails.

I'm not sure if this is related to the problem but I found the following "invalidParams" attribute in the CSVLayer object in case of failure:

> "query contains one or more unsupported parameters"

Any ideas?

Edit: Here's an example of the CSV file:

```
id,x,y,title
1,22.1114,65.5773,"Path 1"
2,22.1453,65.5910,"Path 2"
3,22.1177,65.6076,"Path 3"
4,22.0740,65.6158,"Path 4"
5,22.0290,65.6324,"Path 5"
6,21.9734,65.6500,"Path 6"
7,21.9426,65.6636,"Path 7"
8,22.1546,65.5901,"Path 8"
9,22.1547,65.5950,"Path 9"
10,22.1471,65.6003,"Path 10"
11,22.1385,65.6064,"Path 11"
12,22.1699,65.5957,"Path 12"
13,22.1710,65.6073,"Path 13"
14,22.1691,65.5822,"Path 14"
15,22.1816,65.5821,"Path 15"
16,22.1986,65.5818,"Path 16"
17,22.2258,65.5887,"Path 17"
18,22.1870,65.5792,"Path 18"
19,22.1982,65.5674,"Path 19"
```

Comment: Is there bad data (nulls or invalid x/y) on entry number 19?

Comment: This was actually my first thought too but unfortunately, no...

Comment: Can you post an example CSV that causes this issue?

Comment: It works fine when I test a CSV file with those 19 lines...  Could you create a full sample (maybe jsbin or something)?  Also, which version of the JSAPI are you using?

Answer (score 1):

After some debugging I managed to pinpoint the root cause of the error. The problem is that my map uses a local spatial reference system while the CSVLayer assumes WGS84 by default. The problem is then that the request to project the WGS84 to the local reference system using the GeometryService takes too long to complete for 19 or more datapoints.

I managed found a workaround to the problem by storing the coordinates in the CSV in the local spatial reference system and creating a wrapper for the GeometryService. The wrapper basically prevents the GeometryService from calling the remote server for the projection and replaces the default spatial reference of the Graphics-objects by the local one:

```
define([
    "dojo/_base/declare",
    "dojo/_base/lang",
    "esri/SpatialReference",
    "esri/tasks/GeometryService",
],
function(declare, lang, SpatialReference, GeometryService) {
    return declare(
        [GeometryService],
        {     
            constructor: function(parameters) {
                lang.mixin(this, parameters);
            },

            project: function() {
                var graphics = arguments[0];
                var params = arguments[1];
                var callback = arguments[2];
                var errback = arguments[4];

                // Simply set the spatial reference for each Graphics object
                var spatialReference = new SpatialReference({wkid: 3017});
                for(i = 0; i < graphics.length; i++) {
                    graphics[i].spatialReference = spatialReference;
                }

                // Fire the "project-complete" signal and call possible callbacks
                this._successHandler([graphics], "onProjectComplete", callback);
            },
        }
    );
});
```

**Note:** This works for my little prototype application but it will most certainly break more complex applications. The optimal solution would be if one were able to specify the spatial reference for the CSVLayer but it appears that the API doesn't support that.